# grep search for pipe term Argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have something like

```
grep ... | grep -f - *orders*
```

where the first `grep` ... gives a list of order numbers like

```
1393
3435
5656
4566
7887
6656
```

and I want to find those orders in multiple files (`a_orders_1`, `b_orders_3` etc.), these files look something like

```
1001|strawberry|sam
1002|banana|john
...
```

However, when the first grep... returns too many order numbers I get the error "Argument list too long".

I also tried to give the `grep` command one order number at a time using a while loop but that's just way too slow. I did

```
grep ... | while read order; do grep $order *orders*; done
```

I'm very new to Unix clearly, explanations would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you're escaping the `*` they won't be expanded. Are you sure this code gave the error you described?

Comment: sorry the escaping was not supposed to be there fixed the post now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expansion of `*orders*` in `grep ... | grep -f - *orders*`.  Your shell expands the pattern to the full list of files before passing that list to `grep`.

So we need to pass fewer "orders" files to each `grep` invocation.  The `find` program is one way to do that, because it accepts wildcards and expands them internally:

```
find . -name '*orders*' # note this searches subdirectories too
```

Now that you know how to generate the list of filenames without running into the command line length limit, you can tell `find` to execute your second grep:

```
grep ... | find . -name '*orders*' -exec grep -f - {} +
```

The `{}` is where `find` places the filenames, and the `+` terminates the command and lets `find` know you're OK with passing multiple arguments to each invocation of `grep -f`, while still respecting the command line length limit by invoking `grep -f` more than once if the list of files exceeds the allowed length of a single command.

Comment: I believe this will fail. If find runs `grep -f -` more than once (due to a large number of matching files), the first instance will consume stdin, and any subsequent instances will have no pattern list. You need to either use a regular file for the pattern list (not FIFO), or perhaps -exec the whole pipeline: `-exec sh -c 'grep ... | grep -f - -- "$@"' _ {} +`.

Comment: Ah i see thanks! So this will fix the problem when there are too many files to search from ( the *orders* files), but what if there's too many order numbers that I want to search for? So I mean if the initial "grep ..." gives a lot of order numbers; will that cause a problem that returns "Argument list too long"?

Comment: @Sam: No, that will not be a problem.  Try it out, but note dan's good feedback, you need to adjust that part or only the first "chunk" of filenames will be processed as you expect.